# Explosion effect in java game

Tags: java, animation, draw

Im trying to get a explosion happening in my game for a mine bomb. Currently i have an int that stores which image to draw. I want it to update the image every .5 of a second but currently it loops through them so fast you cant really see the explosion. Is there any way to extend upon this implementation to obtain an update every .5 seconds ?

Here is the draw method:

```
    @Override
public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
    if (imageNum == 0){
        sprite = new Sprite(Sprite.MINE,this.position,new Vector2D(0,0),this.radius,this.radius,0);
    }else if (imageNum == 1){
        sprite = new Sprite(Sprite.MINE1,this.position,new Vector2D(0,0),this.radius,this.radius,0);
        this.radius = sprite.getRadius();
        imageNum ++;
    }else if (imageNum == 2){
        sprite = new Sprite(Sprite.MINE2,this.position,new Vector2D(0,0),this.radius,this.radius,0);
        this.radius = sprite.getRadius();
        imageNum ++;
    }else if (imageNum == 3){
        sprite = new Sprite(Sprite.MINE3,this.position,new Vector2D(0,0),this.radius,this.radius,0);
        this.radius = sprite.getRadius();
        imageNum ++;
    }else if (imageNum == 4){
        sprite = new Sprite(Sprite.EXPLOSION_4,this.position,new Vector2D(0,0),this.radius,this.radius,0);
        this.radius = sprite.getRadius();
        imageNum ++;
    }else if (imageNum == 5){
        sprite = new Sprite(Sprite.EXPLOSION_5,this.position,new Vector2D(0,0),this.radius,this.radius,0);
        this.radius = sprite.getRadius();
        imageNum ++;
    }else if (imageNum == 6){
        sprite = new Sprite(Sprite.EXPLOSION_6,this.position,new Vector2D(0,0),this.radius,this.radius,0);
        this.radius = sprite.getRadius();
        imageNum ++;
    }else if (imageNum == 7){
        sprite = new Sprite(Sprite.EXPLOSION_7,this.position,new Vector2D(0,0),this.radius,this.radius,0);
        this.radius = sprite.getRadius();
        imageNum ++;
    }else if (imageNum == 8){
        sprite = new Sprite(Sprite.EXPLOSION_6,this.position,new Vector2D(0,0),this.radius,this.radius,0);
        this.radius = sprite.getRadius();
        imageNum ++;
    }else if (imageNum == 9){
        sprite = new Sprite(Sprite.EXPLOSION_5,this.position,new Vector2D(0,0),this.radius,this.radius,0);
        this.radius = sprite.getRadius();
        imageNum ++;
    }else if (imageNum == 10){
        sprite = new Sprite(Sprite.EXPLOSION_4,this.position,new Vector2D(0,0),this.radius,this.radius,0);
        this.radius = sprite.getRadius();
        imageNum ++;
    }else if (imageNum == 11){
        sprite = new Sprite(Sprite.MINE3,this.position,new Vector2D(0,0),this.radius,this.radius,0);
        this.radius = sprite.getRadius();
        imageNum ++;
    }else if (imageNum == 12){
        sprite = new Sprite(Sprite.MINE2,this.position,new Vector2D(0,0),this.radius,this.radius,0);
        this.radius = sprite.getRadius();
        imageNum ++;
    }else if (imageNum == 13){
        sprite = new Sprite(Sprite.MINE1,this.position,new Vector2D(0,0),this.radius,this.radius,0);
        this.radius = sprite.getRadius();
        imageNum = 1;
    }
    sprite.draw(g);
}
```

Comment: you could write a timestamp after the sucessfull setting of a new image and check the current timestamp against the last one. If the difference in time is reached, just do your next update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the delay of 0.5 seconds by sleeping the thread.

Here is the snippet:

```
private void insertDelay(final int DELAY_TIME) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(DELAY_TIME);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Now, you'll just have to call `insertDelay()` every time after you draw an image.

```
sprite.draw(g);
insertDelay(500);
```